# wordpress fullscreen menu with effect

Tags: wordpress, menu

i need to know which plugins are used in this Fullscreen menu in this website:

https://team-wandres.de

i need the Paint effect please! very important.

Thanks!

Comment: By inspecting it looks like it's just a regular menu with an SVG animation in the background.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't use any plugin for this menu, it was created customly

Here you can find some similar animations

```
    html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

https://codepen.io/sndrgb/pen/EperVd

Comment: yeah, but you can take the animation as an example to create yours, the example menu also uses animation with svg